# Limiting Behavior of a Rational Function at Infinity

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the following function:
$$f(x) = \frac{2x^2+x}{x^2-1}$$

I know there's a horizontal asymtote at $y = 2$. Without graphing, is there a way to tell that the $x\rightarrow \infty$ part is approaching from above and the $x \rightarrow -\infty$ is approaching from below?

Comment: Write your function as $f(x) = 2 + g(x)/(x^2-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x > 1$,

$$\frac{2x^2+x}{x^2-1} > \frac{2x^2+1}{x^2-1}>\frac{2x^2-2}{x^2-1}=2$$

Since the denominator is positive and $2x^2+x > 2x^2+1$. So $f(x) \to 2$ from above as $x \to \infty$.

Similarly

For $x< -2$,

$$\frac{2x^2+x}{x^2-1} < \frac{2x^2-2}{x^2-1}=2$$

Since the denominator is positive and $2x^2+x < 2x^2-2$.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the long division or Taylor series (better) to show that, for large values of $x$
$$f(x) = \frac{2x^2+x}{x^2-1}=2+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)=2+\frac{1}{x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ So, when $x \to +\infty$ the asymptote is approached from above  and  when $x \to -\infty$ the asymptote is approached from below.